# Make :hover on Android require two clicks to open a link

Tags: android, css, mobile, navigation, responsive-design

I've built a great, responsive CSS navigation, but I'm having trouble getting it to work in Android without jQuery. In iOS and Windows Phone, when the user taps on a navigation link that has drop downs, the drop down expands. If the user taps on this link a second time, they get taken to that link.

Is there anything similar I can do for Android? Or am I stuck using jQuery?

Example URL: http://bearce.me/nav

Comment: That's what it should look like. Tap on the icon in the top right.

Comment: Interesting. Well there goes that part of the menu, then.

Comment: Made a few changes just now, should work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright< I figured this out. Sadly, there's no way to do it with CSS. I ended up writing some JavaScript that detects if it's Android, and if so, triggers the drop downs in a touch-friendly way. Here's the code, for anyone who's curious:

```
// fixes drop downs in Android
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // fixes drop downs
        $("nav ul li ul, nav ul li ul li ul").parent("li").children("a").each(function() {
            var touched = false;
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                if (touched == true) {
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next("ul").trigger("mouseenter");
                    touched = true;
                }
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                touched = false;
            });
        });
        // fixes menu button
        $("nav > a").each(function() {
            var touched = false;
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (touched == true) {
                    $(this).next("ul").trigger("mouseleave");
                    touched = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).next("ul").trigger("mouseenter");
                    touched = true;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```